# IOS 9 executes CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled and authorizationStatus take longer time than expect

Tags: objective-c, ios9, cllocationmanager

```
- (void) isLocationEnabled: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Loading Location status...");
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult;
       if([self isLocationEnabled] && [self isLocationAuthorized]) {
           pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsInt:1];
       }
       else {
           pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsInt:0]; 
       }
       [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       });
   });
}


- (BOOL) isLocationEnabled
{
   if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
       NSLog(@"Location is enabled.");
       return true;
   } else {
       NSLog(@"Location is disabled.");
       return false;
   }
}  
- (BOOL) isLocationAuthorized
{
   if([CLLocationManager  authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
       NSLog(@"This app is authorized to use location.");
       return true;
   } else {
       NSLog(@"This app is not authorized to use location.");
       return false;
   }
}
```

call isLocationEnabled and see the log, it takes 2 seconds to execute isLocationEnabled and 6 seconds to execute isLocationAuthorized. it happens when we resume the app from background status. any idea?

```
Xcode log:
2015-11-18 15:13:30:840 AppName [4538:60036] Loading Location status...
2015-11-18 15:13:32:103 AppName [4538:60036] Location is enabled.
2015-11-18 15:13:38:345 AppName [4538:60036] This app is authorized to use location.
```

Comment: Did you try calling logging on the main thread (inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`)? And why do you check authorization status in a separate queue at all?